# Best practice for calling methods and variables from/of class

Tags: c#, class

I have the following setup and I'm wondering if what I'm doing is the best approach:

```
Project1 //reusable code and controls
    mainclass.cs
    usercontrol1.xaml
    usercontrol2.xaml

Project2 //referencing Project1
    mainwindow.xaml //containing usercontrol1.xaml and usercontrol2.xaml
```

Project1 contains a class and user controls used in other projects, for example Project2.
As the mainwindow in Project2 is initialized I create a new instance of mainclass and pass it as variable to the usercontrols, I also pass the usercontrols as variables to the mainclass.

In this way from the mainclass I can have access to all public methods and variables in the usercontrols and vice versa. Is this a good approach?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainClass MC = new MainClass();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MC.usercontrol1 = this.usercontrol1;
        MC.usercontrol2 = this.usercontrol2;

        usercontrol1.mainClass = MC;
        usercontrol2.mainClass = MC;
    }
...
```

I know that part of this would be more appropriate if done via Events, but the number of methods and variables I need to cross-access between the class and the usercontrols is very high, and doing this way seems to work just fine...

Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't call it "best practice". Best practice is, as you say, to use Events to provide information to interested subscribers, rather than tightly binding your controls and logic together. Also, databinding your controls to a Model class so that you don't have to "share" any properties. Not to say what you're doing won't work, but it's not the "best practice" way.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a constructor in the `MainClass` since all those classes are in the same project:

```
public MainClass(usercontrol1 uc1, usercontrol2 uc2)
{
    uc1.mainClass = this;
    uc2.mainClass = this;
    this.usercontrol1 = uc1;
    this.usercontrol2 = uc2;
}
```

then,

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainClass MC = new MainClass(this.usercontrol1, this.usercontrol2);
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
...
```

Otherwise I am not sure what you are trying to do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Circular dependencies are bad and tightly bound classes are also bad, since they break the open closed principle...

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but I would suggest another class to compose all three classes or else use events if you can.